# AWS : Using EFS with Fargate/ECS Containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I am attempting to use EFS with Fargate/ECS containers. I have tested the EFS instance using multiple linux instances. I tried to follow the example at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-mount-efs-containers-tasks/

The container throws this error.

*Resourceinitializationerror: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: b'mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 127.0.0.1:/' : unsuccessful EFS utils command execution; code: 32*

The EFS SecurityGroup :

- **Inbound**:
- TCP--2049--10.0.0.0/16  (VPC CIDR)
- All--All--sg-0bd22...  (Container SG ID)
- **Outbound:**
- All--All--0.0.0.0/0

The Container SecurityGroup

- **Inbound:**
- All--All--0.0.0.0/0
- **Outbound:**
- All--All--0.0.0.0/0

This is my task definition:

```
{
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::327425660322:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "environmentFiles": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/prefetch",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "command": null,
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 0,
            "environment": [],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "readOnly": null,
                    "containerPath": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                    "sourceVolume": "efs-html"
                }
            ],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": null,
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": 128,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "nginx",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "firelensConfiguration": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "nginx"
        }
    ],
    "memory": "512",
    "taskRoleArn": null,
    "family": "efs-tutorial",
    "pidMode": null,
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX",
        "cpuArchitecture": null
    },
    "cpu": "256",
    "inferenceAccelerators": [],
    "proxyConfiguration": null,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": {
                "transitEncryptionPort": null,
                "fileSystemId": "fs-0d15c1e9184fffacd",
                "authorizationConfig": {
                    "iam": "DISABLED",
                    "accessPointId": "fsap-04a23206444492e37"
                },
                "transitEncryption": "ENABLED",
                "rootDirectory": "/"
            },
            "name": "efs-html",
            "host": null,
            "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
        }
    ],
    "tags": []
}
```

I also am using the following policies as the task Execution Role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "elasticfilesystem:Backup",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite",
                "elasticfilesystem:CreateFileSystem",
                "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount",
                "elasticfilesystem:CreateMountTarget",
                "elasticfilesystem:CreateTags",
                "elasticfilesystem:CreateAccessPoint",
                "elasticfilesystem:CreateReplicationConfiguration",
                "elasticfilesystem:DeleteFileSystem",
                "elasticfilesystem:DeleteMountTarget",
                "elasticfilesystem:DeleteTags",
                "elasticfilesystem:DeleteAccessPoint",
                "elasticfilesystem:DeleteFileSystemPolicy",
                "elasticfilesystem:DeleteReplicationConfiguration",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeAccountPreferences",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeBackupPolicy",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeFileSystems",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeFileSystemPolicy",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeLifecycleConfiguration",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargets",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeReplicationConfigurations",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeTags",
                "elasticfilesystem:DescribeAccessPoints",
                "elasticfilesystem:ModifyMountTargetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticfilesystem:PutAccountPreferences",
                "elasticfilesystem:PutBackupPolicy",
                "elasticfilesystem:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "elasticfilesystem:PutFileSystemPolicy",
                "elasticfilesystem:UpdateFileSystem",
                "elasticfilesystem:TagResource",
                "elasticfilesystem:UntagResource",
                "elasticfilesystem:ListTagsForResource",
                "elasticfilesystem:Restore",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ListAliases"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "elasticfilesystem.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to fix:

1. The IAM permissions for EFS access need to be on the ECS Task Role, not the ECS Execution Role.
2. You need to enable IAM permission usage on the access point connection settings. You currently have this disabled `"iam": "DISABLED",`. That means that all the IAM permissions you are trying to set are being ignored, and only the EFS volume's resource policy is being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mark B's answer, be sure to double check that your access point is configured with proper POSIX permissions. From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-access-points.html):

> If you do not specify the ownership and permissions for an access point root directory, Amazon EFS will not create the root directory. All attempts to mount the access point will fail.